# Serializing/Deserializing a standalone integer using protocol buffers

Tags: java, c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Up to now, I've been using Protocol Buffers to serialize and deserialize objects using the code-generated classes.

Now I am attempting to serialize and deserialize a single 64-bit integer. The problem is, I'm getting different results in Java and C#.

Here's how I'm doing it in Java....

```
private static byte[] convertLongToByteArray(long value) throws IOException {
    int size = CodedOutputStream.computeInt64SizeNoTag(value);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    CodedOutputStream codedOutputStream = CodedOutputStream.newInstance(buffer);
    codedOutputStream.writeInt64NoTag(value);
    codedOutputStream.flush();
    codedOutputStream.checkNoSpaceLeft();
    return buffer;
}
```

And here's how I'm doing this in C#, using protobuf.net:

```
public void SerializeLongValue()
{
    long n = 9876;
    byte[] memoryBuffer = null;
    using (MemoryStream destination = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(destination, n);
        destination.Flush();
        memoryBuffer = destination.ToArray();
    }

    using (MemoryStream source = new MemoryStream(memoryBuffer))
    {
        long result = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<long>(source);
        Assert.AreEqual(n, result);
    }
}
```

The java code converted the number `9876` to `[0x94, 0x4D]`

The C# code converted the number `9876` to `[0x08, 0x94, 0x4D]`

How do I do this so that both `com.google.protobuf` and `protobuf.net` produce identical outputs?

Comment: Note: in protobuf-net there is the `ProtoWriter` class that works a bit like `CodedOutputStream`; however, I suspect that it will be unhappy writing what is, ultimately, an incomplete / invalid document. In some ways, it seems like you are after something akin to `ProtoReader.DirectReadVarintInt32`, but a: write (not read), and b: 64-bit. A `DirectWriteVarintInt64` method (outside of a `ProtoWriter` instance) does not currently exist.

Comment: @MarcGravell - You suspected correctly. `ProtoWriter.WriteInt64` throws an exception if the wire type is not set appropriately, and you can only set the wire type by invoking `ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader`.

Answer (score 2):

The protobuf.net method `ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize` forces a field header (field number=1) into the stream. That's the only way you can perform a serialization; this method invokes a number of internal methods which are not publicly available.

The solution I'm using is to change the Java code to also include a field header.

Here is my new Java code.

```
private static byte[] convertLongToByteArray(long value) throws IOException {
    int size = CodedOutputStream.computeTagSize(1) + CodedOutputStream.computeInt64SizeNoTag(value);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    CodedOutputStream codedOutputStream = CodedOutputStream.newInstance(buffer);
    codedOutputStream.writeInt64(1, value);
    codedOutputStream.flush();
    codedOutputStream.checkNoSpaceLeft();
    return buffer;
}

public static long convertByteArrayToLong(byte[] byteArray) throws IOException {
    CodedInputStream codedInputStream = CodedInputStream.newInstance(byteArray);
    codedInputStream.readTag();
    return codedInputStream.readInt64();
}
```

The changes I've made are:

- When computing the required buffer size, include a tag size
- Instead of `CodedOutputStream.WriteInt64NoTag`, call `CodedOutputStream.WriteInt64`
- When reading back, call `CodedOutputStream.ReadTag` before calling `CodedOutputStream.ReadInt64`

Comment: That's good to know, thanks for sharing. I'm considering using protobuf to communicate with a Java program I have no control over.